# How to use javascript validations for controls within ListView EditTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

In [Nridubai](http://nridubai.com) website,i am  using listview EditTemplate for editing purpose.  In my EditTemplate, there are controls like..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditEventName" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("event_name") %>' />
```

And a few more controls like dropdownlist, calender controls.  Now I want to validate using javascript on these controls, but its not working.

Eg.

```
var eventStatus=document.getElementById("<%=txtEditEventName.ClientID%>").value;
```

I am not using validation controls.  Please help me how to use javascript for validation on EditTemplate Controls?  My EditTemplate structure is like the following:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                                        <td class="command"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                                        </td>
                                        <div class="header">View Details for &#39;<%# Eval("event_name")%>&#39;</div>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="edit" colspan="6" >
                                            <div class="details">
                                                <table class="detailview"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>


                <td>Event Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditEventName" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("event_name") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td>VenueAddress :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditVenue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("venue") %>' />
                </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>

                <td>Country :</td>
                <td>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="lstEditCountry" runat="server" 


                              Width="174" />



                </td>


                <td>Event Status:</td>
                <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstEditStatus" runat="server" Width="175px"  >
                                        <asp:ListItem value='0' Selected="True">-Select-</asp:ListItem>

 <asp:ListItem  >In-Progress</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem  >Completed</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem  >Aborted</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:DropDownList>

                </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Category :</td>
                <td>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="lstEditCategory" runat="server" 


                              Width="174" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td>Start Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditStartDate" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("start_date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>End Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditEndDate" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("end_date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                </td>


                </tr>






                                                </table>
                                               <div class="footer command">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Close" CommandName="Cancel" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: we need more than that to provide you with working code to validate values. Provide us complete markup of edittemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the elements on `ItemDataBound` and emit their `ClientIDs` for your JavaScript to use:

**ItemDataBound:**

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder vars= new StringBuilder();

    if (ListView1.EditItem != null)
    {
        TextBox txtEditStartDate = ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("txtEditStartDate") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtEditEndDate = ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("txtEditEndDate") as TextBox;

        //example js, however I recommend passing the ClientIDs to functions
        vars.Append(String.Format("var txtEditStartDate='{0}';" txtEditStartDate.ClientID);
        vars.Append(String.Format("var txtEditStartDate='{0}';", txtEditEndDate.ClientID );
        ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this.GetType(), "validationVars", vars.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

---

******Old Answer, the .NET way*************************

**EditTemplate:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditEventName" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("event_name") %>' />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                    id="rfvEditEventName" 
                    ClientValidationFunction="txtEditEventNameClientValidate"      
                    ControlToValidate="txtTitle"
                    runat="server"      
                    Display="dynamic">*
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**JS:**

```
function txtEditEventNameClientValidate(sender, args) { 
    if (args.Value == '') {
        args.IsValid = false;  // field is empty      
        //so something
    } 
    else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankssss... I want only javascript. and i used var v = $('#<%=txtEditEventName.ClientID%>');  But it shows error doesnot Exists..  Please help me.........

Comment: See update, added another way to pass the ClientIDs to the client-side.

Comment: Sorry about the error, that line in the .NET way code should not have been there, I removed it.

Comment: Sir i Edit code like    StringBuilder vars = new StringBuilder();                  vars.Append(String.Format("var txtEditStartDate='{0}';", listCat.ClientID));
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "validationVars", vars.ToString(), true);
now how to retrieve these values on client side......

Comment: They will be global js variables(txtEditStartDate and txtEditStartDate). Try alerting them in your validation function.

Comment: I have tried to retrieve these 2 globalVariable(txtEditStartDate and txtEditStartDate).It working nice on on normal button.but when i put that code in OnItemUpdating event on EditTemplate's LinkButton its not working.  EX   vars.Append(String.Format("var txtEditStartDate12='{0}';", "CRm"));    I passed just string to test.

Answer (score 0):

Put the validation javascript in the EditTemplate itself.  This way, when it switches to edit-mode, the control will be in the context.

Comment: I put javascript code in editTemplate but it giving me same error.

Comment: I am not finding Edittemplate controls in javascript for validation.